# How to style a list inside a list

Tags: html, css

I have an unordered list inside another unordered list, surrounded by paragraphs. I have styled my list items to be larger than the paragraphs inside it, but I want the list inside of the list to be the same size as the paragraphs.

Here's an example:

```css
p {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 125%;
}
h3 {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 170%;
    font-weight: bold;
}
li {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 150%;
    font-style: italic;
}
li > ul > li {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<h3>These are the top-most misconceptions about aromanticism:</h3>
    <ul>
        <li>That we are unfeeling or "cold fish"</li>
            <p>Nothing could be further from the truth. Just because we have no interest in romantic love does not make us any less funny, warm, kind or happy people.</p>
        <li>That we are lonely or have no love in our lives</li>
            <p>This is a huge misconception. Romantic love has been such a focus of movies, tv-shows, songs and books, that people forget that there are many other forms of love that are equally - if not more - important. For example:</p>
            <ul>
                <li>Self-love: Loving yourself, feeling good in your own skin.</li>
                <li>Familial love: Loving your family, whether that family is the one you're born into or choose for yourself</li>
                <li>Amicable love: Loving your friends. This, for aromantic people, is often a stronger bond than what non-aromantics experience, since friendship for us is not a temporary relationship that can fade once a "more important" romantic relationship starts.</li>
                <li>Love for animals</li>
                <li>Love for hobbies</li>
            </ul>
            <br>
        <li>That we are broken</li>
```

I have tried with

li li, li > ul, tried moving the list items inside the paragraph and then using p li

I've even tried removing the original list styling, just to see if it's blocking it, but then none of the lists get any styling.

Please help?

Comment: set a class on your inner eg `<ul class="innerList">` and change `li > ul > li` to `.innerList li`. And make sure that your browser which you're testing is actually loading the updated css file.

Comment: You shouldn't put `<p>` between `<li>` element.

Comment: To expand on @Chaska’s comment - also neither `ul` or `br` are allowed as children of `ul` either. You need to wrap those into the `li` you have on that level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you think about this?

```css
p, .internal {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 125%;
  font-style: normal;
}
h3 {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 170%;
    font-weight: bold;
}
li {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 150%;
    font-style: italic;
}
li > ul > li {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<h3>These are the top-most misconceptions about aromanticism:</h3>
    <ul>
        <li>That we are unfeeling or "cold fish"</li>
            <p>Nothing could be further from the truth. Just because we have no interest in romantic love does not make us any less funny, warm, kind or happy people.</p>
        <li>That we are lonely or have no love in our lives</li>
            <p>This is a huge misconception. Romantic love has been such a focus of movies, tv-shows, songs and books, that people forget that there are many other forms of love that are equally - if not more - important. For example:</p>
            <ul>
                <li class="internal">Self-love: Loving yourself, feeling good in your own skin.</li>
                <li class="internal">Familial love: Loving your family, whether that family is the one you're born into or choose for yourself</li>
                <li class="internal">Amicable love: Loving your friends. This, for aromantic people, is often a stronger bond than what non-aromantics experience, since friendship for us is not a temporary relationship that can fade once a "more important" romantic relationship starts.</li>
                <li class="internal">Love for animals</li>
                <li class="internal">Love for hobbies</li>
            </ul>
            <br>
        <li>That we are broken</li>
```

I just added `.internal` class on the internal `li`, in order to make the elements that have that class with the same style of `p`.

**Edit:** Added `font-style: normal` to avoid italic showing for `p` and `.internal`

Comment: Thank you this was exactly how I meant! 
Can you explain why my code didn't work and what this internal class means? 

Sorry, I'm new :)

Comment: Not a problem! **Basics:** Well, HTML is a Markup language where you write the page structure, so it's a code composed by a lot of elements... instead, CSS is a language where you define the style of the structure, that means you write how to show the page for the user (sometimes also with crossplatform compatibility, like mobiles). The **reason** because your code was not able to provide what you were looking for was about this: HTML elements has some elements with a default style, so to avoid this you need to edit one or more CSS properties in one or more elements.

Comment: To make your inner list elements affected by the CSS code, you need to put `class="internal"` for each element in the internal list

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of approaches to resolve:

- Use css classes like outerList and innerList. The style will follow and be consistent. Please use your own naming convention. I am not good at them.
- Create a jsfiddle and try different combinations. I guess ul > li ul >li should do. It is not a recommended approach though.

Comment: I'm very new at this.

Could you explain outerList and innerList?

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem you could add a class to the 2º set of list items. Adding a class makes it so much easier to edit properties (easier to find) :)

```
  <h3>These are the top-most misconceptions about aromanticism:</h3>
<ul>
    <li>That we are unfeeling or "cold fish"</li>
    <p>Nothing could be further from the truth. Just because we have no interest in romantic love does not make us any less funny, warm, kind or happy people.</p>
    <li>That we are lonely or have no love in our lives</li>
    <p>This is a huge misconception. Romantic love has been such a focus of movies, tv-shows, songs and books, that people forget that there are many other forms of love that are equally - if not more - important. For example:</p>
    <ul>
        <li class="sublist" f-love: Loving yourself, feeling good in your own skin.</li>
            <li class="sublist">Familial love: Loving your family, whether that family is the one you're born into or choose for yourself</li>
            <li class="sublist">Amicable love: Loving your friends. This, for aromantic people, is often a stronger bond than what non-aromantics experience, since friendship for us is not a temporary relationship that can fade once a "more important" romantic relationship starts.</li>
            <li class="sublist">Love for animals</li>
            <li class="sublist">Love for hobbies</li>
    </ul>
    <br>
    <li>That we are broken</li>enter code here


p {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 125%;
}

h3 {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 170%;
    font-weight: bold;
}

li {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 150%;
    font-style: italic;
}

.sublist {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your *inner* `ul li` isn't actually nested inside any of the *outer* `li`s.
You indented your code as if it is, but all of the outer `li`s are closed on the same line as they are opened.

So all you have to do is properly nest your DOM elements, and you're set.
Forget all the adding of classes et cetera, has nothing to do with it.

Same goes for the nesting of all your `p`s, at least I assume you want those inside the `li`s.
And your outer `ul` is not closed btw, but that's another issue.

```css
p {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 125%;
}
h3 {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 170%;
    font-weight: bold;
}
li {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 150%;
    font-style: italic;
}
li > ul > li {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<h3>These are the top-most misconceptions about aromanticism:</h3>
    <ul>
        <li>That we are unfeeling or "cold fish"
            <p>Nothing could be further from the truth. Just because we have no interest in romantic love does not make us any less funny, warm, kind or happy people.</p>
        </li>
        <li>That we are lonely or have no love in our lives
            <p>This is a huge misconception. Romantic love has been such a focus of movies, tv-shows, songs and books, that people forget that there are many other forms of love that are equally - if not more - important. For example:</p>
            <ul>
                <li>Self-love: Loving yourself, feeling good in your own skin.</li>
                <li>Familial love: Loving your family, whether that family is the one you're born into or choose for yourself</li>
                <li>Amicable love: Loving your friends. This, for aromantic people, is often a stronger bond than what non-aromantics experience, since friendship for us is not a temporary relationship that can fade once a "more important" romantic relationship starts.</li>
                <li>Love for animals</li>
                <li>Love for hobbies</li>
            </ul>
            <br>
        </li>
        <li>That we are broken</li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: @Sofia I urge you to have a look at my answer, you are clearly new at programming in HTML, and if you don't get this right from the get-go and use sloppy patches to cover up your mistakes, you will ruin your coding abilities later on. The other answers on here are well-intended, but wrong, 'cause they all missed the actual cause.